# How to remove the double quotes in the JSON?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

From the database I get JSON in the following manner

```
 String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.apps/databases/";
 String myPath = DB_PATH + DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME;// Set path to your database
 String myTable = DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACT;//Set name of your table
 SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null );

    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for(int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++) {
            if(cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                try {
                    if(cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                    } else {
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        json.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME_ALL", json.toString());
    return json.toString();
```

JSON coming out correct, except for one value **latlng**.

I get - **"latlng": "[12.3456789,98.7654321]"**

Need to get - **"latlng": [12.3456789,98.7654321]**

How to get rid from double quotes?

Comment: `cursor.getString(i)` is a string, and hence is formatted by json as a string. What you can do is `new JSONArray(cursor.getString(i))`

Comment: how correct getDouble for latlng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a quick and dirty way to convert that response to double values, you can do this:

```
String s = "[12.3456789,98.7654321]";
String trimmed = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
String[] parts = trimmed.split(",");
double lat = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
double lng = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
Log.d("latlng", "lat="+lat+"  lng="+lng);
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: i need to get in JSON file "latlng": [12.3456789,98.7654321] without double quotes.

Comment: or, you could simply realize that `[...]` is a json array, and use the built in json parser to parse it.

Comment: it help me ! very thanks

                String latlng = jsonObj.getString("latlng");
                String trimmed = latlng.substring(1, latlng.length() - 1);
                String[] parts = trimmed.split(",");
                lat = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
                lng = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);